# How do I run a webmethod with jQuery Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

**How do I run a webmethod with jQuery. Asp.Net
the method load it the GridView**

```
[WebMethod]
        public void GetGrid()
        {
            DataProviderDataContext db = new DataProviderDataContext();
            GridView1.DataSource = db.Employees.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question, you can't have a WebMethod that's not static in a page, so it can't reference a `GridView1` control...this isn't valid ASP.Net, so jQuery, nor anything else, can call this method.  I would read up a bit more on Page methods to understand what's allowed: http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx

Comment: I want to do without asp.net scriptmaneger, How can I do ;?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't do this, not the way you want.  Server controls execute on the server, their rendered HTML is what's set to the client, you can't just update a client section of the page from a server-control, there are extra steps (an [UpdatePanel](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/), for a quick-fix approach for example).

I think there are some basic confusion areas here around client/server and how ASP.Net works with with server controls.  I recommend that you look at how-to's using ASP.Net with jQuery AJAX, encosia has some excellent articles for just this:

- [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)
- [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)